Postgres foreign key on table that's not accessible by user
I have two tables, users and appointments.
The appointments table has a foreign key (appointments.user_id) relationship with the users.id column to link the appointment to the user who created it.
I'm now trying to allow a second user (listed in appointments.guest_id) to edit the appointments rows where they are listed as guests.
The users table has a Row Security Level policy that only allows users to see their own row.
When the guest tries to edit the appointment row, the user id relationship check fails, likely because the guest can't see the appointment owner user row.
So the schema looks like the following:
appointments.user_id (uuid) > users.id
appointments.guest_id (uuid)

users.id (uuid)

How can I fix this issue?

One approach could be to create a policy that grants access to appointment rows for users listed as guests, regardless of the row ownership. Then you can implement code validations to ensure code modification is only done by user.id that matches appointment.guest_id.

Thanks but I would like to keep the users rows private since there's a lot of sensitive data in them

you can filter out what kind of data is shown to users depending on their role but both roles will have access to it

are you suggesting to use column level security rules?

I'm suggesting the security should be on the object, which only gives access to only user or guest on the object
